# Joining tables and aggregation/sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, aggregation

I have 2 tables as show below.

Table1

| Order ID | Item_code | Sales_Price | Qty_ordered | Total | Qty shipped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 111 | 10 | 5 | $50 | 1 |
| 1000 | 222 | 20 | 10 | $200 | 2 |
| 1000 | 333 | 30 | 15 | $450 | 0 |

I have another table that stores only the details of how much was invoiced (i.e. how much we shipped)

Table2 (because we shipped only 10x1 and 20x2 = $50)

| Order ID | Invoice_total |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | $50 |

I wrote the following query,

```
select T1.Order_ID, 
       sum(T1.Qty_Ordered) as Qty_Ordered, 
       sum(T1.Total) as Total_Amt_ordered, 
       sum(T1.Qty_shipped) as Qty_Shipped, 
       sum(T2.Invoice_total) 
  from T1 join 
       T2 on T1.Order_ID = T2.Order_ID
```

This query gives me the following output, (It is adding $50 to all the rows of T1 Orders).

| Order ID | Qty_ordered | Total | Qty shipped | Invoice_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 30 | $700 | 3 | $150 |

Whereas now, I want my output to be as:

| Order ID | Qty_ordered | Total | Qty shipped | Invoice_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 30 | $700 | 3 | $50 |

(because we shipped only $50)

What changes should I make to my query?
I know I can just hard code it but my database has 1000's of orders and 1000's of Half shipped Orders. I want to keep track of Shipped $ (Invoiced $) for all the orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
select T2.Order_ID, T2.Invoice_total, 
       sum(T1.Qty_Ordered) as Qty_Ordered, 
       sum(T1.Total) as Total_Amt_ordered, 
       sum(T1.Qty_shipped) as Qty_Shipped, 
from T2 join 
     T1
     on T1.Order_ID = T2.Order_ID
group by T2.Order_ID, T2.Invoice_total;
```

That is, you don't want to aggregate `Invoice_total`.  You just want it to be a `group by` key.